# Who have MADE their way to get here and now WORK as

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

Let's say you are a well-versed Filipino engineer who has been employed in Great Britain, and is now an employee there. Then, a racist has questioned your credentials, and you say:

> We're no amateurs, all foreign engineers **who have made their own way to get here**, and **who now work as engineers** for different employers are experienced and highly competent.

Are both of my relative clause **grammatical**?

P.S:”made their way” as they have passed several exams including ENGLISH TEST!(hehe)

Comment: I think you mean "…question your credential(s)…" Credibility refers to someone's honesty or their trustworthiness.

Comment: Re the postscript. "Make their way" really only means "travelled in their intended direction", it doesn't imply anything about exams.

Comment: @JamesK I wasn't sure if the OP might have meant "make their **own** way," though. That could be applied to passing exams. It's problematic though since "to get here" seems to take it back to the "traveled" meaning.

Comment: Thx for the corrections, I'm editing it now. So it's ''made their own way to get here'' now, which I mean:who have passed the exam to be able to get to their desired country. Is it ok now?

Comment: @JohnArvin After your edit, I would say it's grammatical and makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence in quotes is absolutely fine, “who” is used correctly in both clauses but personally, I'd leave out “for different employers” because it is a little redundant. I doubt *all* foreign engineers work *for the same **company*** :-)